# Named template up from child to grandparent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need the named template to get from `home-page` to `page-layout` but it doesn't seem to go up that far. If I place the named template closer it works.

`home-page` gets loaded into the `router-view`.

`<page-layout></page-layout>`

```
<template>
 <div>
  <slot name="nav"></slot>
</div>
</template>
```

`<page></page>`

```
<page-layout>
 <router-view></router-view>
</page-layout>
```

`<home-page></home-page>`

```
<template>
 <div>
  <template slot="nav">Nav menu</template>
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Slots aren't passed automatically. You need to pass it explicitly to route comp, e.g. here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#transitions use `<component :is="Component"><slot name="nav"/></component>`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.